# python reading specific lines from CSV using list comprehension

Tags: python, file-io, list-comprehension

Is it possible to make python read only chosen lines from a file?

Let's say I've got a CSV file, file is separated by `tab` and the **third** column is either 'a', 'b' or 'c'. I would like to have a list comprehension (or a generator, doesn't matter) which would return only those lines in the file which have chosen first column

The following throws a syntax error:

```
lines = [tmp = line.rstrip().split(separator_column) for line in source if tmp[2] == 'a']
```

Is it possible to do it in a more pythonic way than just a for-loop? So called more pythonic ways are working with the speed of C - they're faster than basic Python instructions - that's why I ask.

Comment: I would say the Pythonic way is to use a for-loop. Explicit and obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv
with open("your/file.csv", ...) as source:
    reader = csv.reader(source, delimiter='\t')
    selection = [row for row in reader if row[2] == 'a']
```